# Transformar dados recebidos do VeederRoot

Tags: delphi, ascii, porta-serial

Boa tarde Pessoa, Já procurei em vários lugares e ainda não achei a solução para meu problema, espero que vocês possam me ajudar.
 
Estou fazendo uma comunicação em delphi com o veederRoot atravez da porta serial,
o veederRoot so aceita enviar comando ASCII, até ai tudo bem. O problema é quando eu pego a resposta na porta serial e retorno dentro de um Tmemo.
 A resposta é a seguinte:

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf i201001601221037011000007467058F6466D731A466D970B44A00BE9000000‚ - 64

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf 0041EC634C0000000002200000745502CCD454D561545DA799A4464B89300000æ - 64

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf 00041FFBE0D000000002J - 19

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf 033000007449508CD44923215460EA6E743DC20D4000000004200C7B20000000‚ - 64

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf 0$ - 1

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf 044000007457FF5EC457D1F3445C2950A448556530000000042054A9E0000000 - 64

Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf 00Ò - 1
Ta pegando do RxBuf - rxbuf &&C623 - 7

O componente que estou usando para se comunicar com a porta serial é o TComport. Nessa mensagem eu consegui separar so isso: 
Codigo - Data e Hora -  Tanque 
i20100   16//01/22 10:37 -  01 
O resto da mensagem nao estou conseguindo desvendar. Segue a estrutura desse retorno:
Mensagem de Resposta Típica, formato de computador:

i201TTYYMMDDHHmmTTpssssNNFFFFFFFF...
                TTpssssNNFFFFFFFF && CCCC 
 Notas: 
    1. YYMMDDHHmm - data e hora atuais
    2. TT - número do tanque (Decimal, 00 = all) 
        3. p - código do produto (um caractere ASCII [20h-7EH]) 
    4. ssss - Bits de Status Tank:
                 Bit 1 - (LSB) Entrega em andamento 
                 Bit 2 - Teste de vazamento em andamento 
                 Bit 3 - Inválido Alarme de Combustível Altura (Sondas MAG Only)
 
                 Bit 16/04 - Não usado 
    5. NN - Número de oito caracteres de dados Campos a seguir (Hex) 
    6. FFFFFFFF - ASCII Hex IEEE flutua: 
                 1. Volume 
                 2. TC Volume 
                 3. Ullage 
                 4. Altura 
                 5. Água
                 6. Temperatura Volume 
                 7. Água 
    7. && - Bandeira Rescisão de Dados 
    8. CCCC - Checksum Mensagem

Segue um link para mais detalhes(pag.59) https://translate.google.com.br/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chipkin.com%2Ffiles%2Fliz%2F576013-635.pdf&edit-text=